# calling a function written in freefem++ software, from python2.7

Tags: python, function, interface, call, freefem++

I write a code in python and I have a function (f, written in Freefem++) that the inputs come from the code in python. the problem is that I don't know how to call that function written in freefem++, in my python code.

This code is in python and the function "f", assumes to be in Freefem++.

```
 for i in range (popsize):

         pop[i][N]=f(pop[i][0],pop[i][1])
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the function receives the inputs from the python code and returns a single value to python code (pop[i][N]).

Answer (score 0):

Freefem++ is written in C++ and to my knowledge, there is no API written in C++ to allow communications between Freefem++ and Python.

What I would advise is the following:

1. Write your FreeFem++ code and imbed in your code a section to save the data to a temporary file. It is also possible to directly "cout" the result and to read the standard output from Python using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.
2. Call your FreeFem code from python. Say the code is name "simulation.edp", then from python you could write your code as:

```py
import subprocess
dep_file_path="simulation.edp"
bashCommand = ["Freefem++",  edp_file_path]
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

This way, you should be able to read the output of the FreeFem simulation by executing the python code.

3. Read with python the output of you FreeFem++ code (either the std output using the subprocess module or the content of a file outputted by your "simulation.edp") and then process it.

You could try a more direct approach by working in C++ but this path is much harder due to the lack of good documentation on the development of FreeFem++ kernel. Here, you will find some examples of how to interface simple C++ classes with FreeFem++ [Link to Githb](https://gh4ag.github.io/freefem_class_examples/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of A.G. is good but I want to remark, that you can make use of pipes, that allows you to communicate between two programs without the use of files, which are a bottle neck. See for example here [Pipeline (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software))